# How to make this javascript code better than?

Tags: javascript, rating

I have code to render five star rating base on the rating, I think it very easy for everybody but I don't have any idea to make this code better.

@T.J. Crowder have the idea to solve this:

```
// Flags for whether to show stars, based on `average` being
// a fractional number `0 <= average < 5`
var stars = [
    average > 0,
    average > 1,
    average > 2,
    average > 3,
    average > 4
];
```

How to implement this or anyone have any ideas to make this code better?

```
var result = '';
var one_star = '';
var two_star = '';
var three_star = '';
var four_star = '';
var five_star = '';

if(data == 0) {}
else if(data == 1) {
    one_star = 'star-rating-on';
    two_star = '';
    three_star = '';
    four_star = '';
    five_star = '';
}
else if(data == 2) {
    one_star = 'star-rating-on';
    two_star = 'star-rating-on';
    three_star = '';
    four_star = '';
    five_star = '';
}
else if(data == 3) {
    one_star = 'star-rating-on';
    two_star = 'star-rating-on';
    three_star = 'star-rating-on';
    four_star = '';
    five_star = '';
}
else if(data == 4) {
    one_star = 'star-rating-on';
    two_star = 'star-rating-on';
    three_star = 'star-rating-on';
    four_star = 'star-rating-on';
    five_star = '';
}
else if(data == 5) {
    one_star = 'star-rating-on';
    two_star = 'star-rating-on';
    three_star = 'star-rating-on';
    four_star = 'star-rating-on';
    five_star = 'star-rating-on';
}

result += '<span class="star-rating-control">';
result += '<div class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly '+ one_star +'"><a title="Poor">1</a></div>';
result += '<div class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly '+ two_star +'"><a title="OK/Fair">2</a></div>';
result += '<div class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly '+ three_star +'"><a title="Good">3</a></div>';
result += '<div class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly '+ four_star +'"><a title="Great">4</a></div>';
result += '<div class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly '+ five_star +'"><a title="Excellent">5</a></div>';
result += '</span>';
```

Comment: Start using a switch instad if/elseif/else

Comment: What about use a for loop and an array?

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta, I know that case but it will the same with if/else, is it another solution, or I just have two options: if/else or switch/case? it still repeat alot of code not neccessary

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa yes i can loop array to check if it true or false to combine string, but don't want repeat one_star, two_star,... five times, any solution to reduce it?

Comment: That's why I suggested also an array.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa can you explain more detail? I understand but not clearly.

Comment: @GaruJwon: have a look at the second half of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want could basically be done just in a loop:

```
var i
  , on
  , titles = [null, 'Poor', 'Ok/Fair', 'Good', 'Great', 'Excellent']
  , result = '<span class="star-rating-control">';
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  on = data >= i ? 'star-rating-on' : '';
  result += '<div class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly ' + on +'"><a title="' + titles[i] + '">' + i + '</a></div>'
}
result += '</span>';
```

that is all you need, see a working example here (i set data to 3 in the example): http://jsfiddle.net/k7sVC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var one_star = '', two_star = '', three_star = '', four_star = '', five_star = '';
if(data == 1) { one_star   = 'star-rating-on'; }
if(data <= 2) { two_star   = 'star-rating-on'; }
if(data <= 3) { three_star = 'star-rating-on'; }
if(data <= 4) { four_star  = 'star-rating-on'; }
if(data <= 5) { five_star  = 'star-rating-on'; }
```

This sets all variables to `''` as default, then adds as much `star-rating-on` as needed.

---

Or, with an array:

```
var star = ['','','','',''];
for(var i = 0; i < star.length && i <= data -1; i++){
    star[i] = 'star-rating-on';
}

var baseDiv = '<div class="star-rating rater-5 star star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly ';
result += '<span class="star-rating-control">'
  + baseDiv + star[0] +'"><a title="Poor">1</a></div>'
  + baseDiv + star[1] +'"><a title="OK/Fair">2</a></div>'
  + baseDiv + star[2] +'"><a title="Good">3</a></div>'
  + baseDiv + star[3] +'"><a title="Great">4</a></div>'
  + baseDiv + star[4] +'"><a title="Excellent">5</a></div>'
  + '</span>';
```

Comment: The first Example not working, it alway show 4 star-rating-on, although I change the data with different value, but the seconds is work very well

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the fact that once a switch condition has evaluated to true then it will continue to execute all further conditions until it encounters a break. Try the following:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stars"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
html='';
num=4;
switch(num) {
    case 5:
        html+="*";
    case 4:
        html+="*";
    case 3:
        html+="*";
    case 2:
        html+="*";
    case 1:
        html+="*";
    }
document.getElementById("stars").innerHTML=html;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no, it not simple like that, it the same with if/else of my code